# Can't access shared folder in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows

So I configured a brand new virtual machine on a server running ESXi 6 and installed Windows Server 2012. I have added Active Directory and DNS roles. I also created a shared folder, but I can't seem to access it using another computer in the network. It seems that if I remove the Everyone group in the sharing permissions and add another group such as Administrators, I can't access it at all using administrator accounts. For some reason, if I remove the Everyone group I can't access the shared folder at all, but if I added back then I can access the shared folder.
I don't want Everyone to be able to have access, only domain admins should have access. But I can't seem to figure out why it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First, let me start with the fact that there are two permission types for shared folders in Windows and the security table that's checked when somebody accesses the shared resource takes into account both of these permission types.

And then let's clear up the permission types in Windows:

1st you have "share permissions" - accessed via (for example) right click on shared folder on server hosting it -> properties -> sharing -> advanced sharing -> permissions. By default you have the Everyone group here. Best practice is to remove Everyone group and add Authenticated users with full control permissions (I will clear out why below).

2nd you have "ntfs permisssion" - accessed via (for example) right click on shared folder on server hosting it -> properties -> security. Since the resultant security policies take into account both permission types you just control the access to the folder here - you set up through your entire organisation shared permissions that give access to all authenticated users of your domain to the resource and set up the "actual" security via ntfs permissions - for example, add access only to domain admins.

By default Windows only allows users to access folders if they have permissions for it - meaning you don't ever need to use "deny" permissions to deny somebody access to a folder, if you didn't explicitly give them access to the folder they won't have it. So to make sure only domain admins can access that particular folder simply set up full control shared permissions for auth. users, add full control to the domain admins group via ntfs permissions and you'd be done.

PS - best recommendation again (also it's generally easier if you do it like this :)) is to set up 3 domain local groups per shared folder and assign them the following ntfs permissions on the folder - full control, write/modify, read only and simply add the users/groups to the respective access group - that way it's much easier to audit access to a folder, and to see which folders can a user access with what permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add something here.  Everything in the above answer is correct, but also make sure that in your GPO, when you are specifying the roaming profile path to use the Share path, not the logical path.  For instance, instead of `\\servername\d$\sharefolder`, it should be `\\servername\sharename`.  It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

after having followed the instruction you provided, I had no luck, however i decided to do all the updates, even to the optional updates
might be sheer luck or it (might be a combination of all) however after doing so
my last updates were as followed
installed Kb3121461
qualiy rollup for .Netframework 3.5, 4.5.2,4.6,4.6.1 ...
.Net framework 4.7
kb3102429
kb3084905
kb 3012429
in essence do all the updates and voila!
works fine now...
that was my workaround